# List: set method causing problems - IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, indexoutofboundsexception

I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I try to call the `tableUpdate` method.
I think there is something wrong with the way I am using the `set()` method. I have tried with putting `a -1` like this `int row = members.size() -1` but that didn't solve it. Can you please help me?

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        /**
                 *
                 */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();

        public MyTableModel(List<Member> members) {
                this.members = members;
        }

        public void addMember(Member m) {
                members.add(m);
                int row = members.size() - 1;
                fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }

        public void removeMemberFromTable(int row) {
                members.remove(row);
                fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        }

        public void tableUpdate(int row, Member m) {
                row = members.size();
                members.set(row, m);
                fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
        }

        public List<Member> getMembers() {
                return new ArrayList<Member>(members);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
                return 8;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
                return members.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                Member m = members.get(rowIndex);

                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                        return m.getMemberId();

                case 1:
                        return m.getfName();

                case 2:
                        return m.getlName();

                case 3:
                        return m.getAddress();

                case 4:
                        return m.getZipCode();

                case 5:
                        return m.getCity();

                case 6:
                        return m.getEmail();

                case 7:
                        return m.getPhoneNo();

                default:
                        return "";
                }
        }

        public String getColumnName(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                case 0:
                        return "MedlemsID";

                case 1:
                        return "Fornavn";

                case 2:
                        return "Efternavn";

                case 3:
                        return "Adresse";

                case 4:
                        return "Postnummer";

                case 5:
                        return "By";

                case 6:
                        return "Email";

                case 7:
                        return "Telefonnr";
                default:
                        return "";
                }
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                        return String.class;

                case 1:
                        return String.class;

                case 2:
                        return String.class;

                case 3:
                        return String.class;

                case 4:
                        return String.class;

                case 5:
                        return String.class;

                case 6:
                        return String.class;

                case 7:
                        return String.class;

                default:
                        return String.class;
                }
        }
```

EXCEPTION

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:397)
        at gui.MyTableModel.tableUpdate(ShowMembersGUI.java:179)
        at gui.EditMemberGUI$1.actionPerformed(EditMemberGUI.java:108)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite the `row` parameter with the size? Shoudln't that be the position where you insert the `Member`? You should check that `row` is smaller than size, but not change it.

Comment: tableUpdate is supposed to put Member at row index, correct?

Comment: When I remove that line with the size I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 ...

Comment: The method is called after I have updated in the database so it updates both in the database and in the table.

Comment: @user3008922 (Moving this discussion here to not spam Jeroen unnecessarily) While the answer takes care of the exception, there seems to be another problem with your code: It seems the method is called with the parameter `row` set to `-1`, which does not make sense and caused the Exception in the first place. So the question is: What is `row` really supposed to mean? Is `-1` a valid input (meaning, like, "append to the end" or something), or is there an error in the code using the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace the element after the last. It doesn't make sense. Maybe you want to check if the index is within bounds, like this:

```
public void tableUpdate(int row, Member m) {
    if (row < members.size()) {
        members.set(row, m);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it gives me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 .

Comment: ok, then like this:
if (row >= 0 && row < members.size()) {...}
Note that this will just ignore the cases where you try to replace a non-existent position. You may want to check the calling code why it tries to do that, it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have made that myself. :-)

Comment: Okay, but now the row is not set at all... why is `row==-1` in the first place? What's it supposed to mean?

Comment: Check/debug the code at ShowMembersGUI.java line 179. According to the stack trace, that's where it decides to replace value -1.

Comment: @user3008922 Hate to tell, but if you check for `row >= 0` and `row` is `-1` then there is no exception, but the method is not doing anything at all. What's `row` supposed to be, and why is it `-1` when the method is called? (@Jeroen sorry for spamming you)

Comment: Why does it work as it should @tobias_k? Very weird. Everything seems fine now. I know I didn't handle the error properly.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are zero indexed.  This means the last element is at size - 1, not size.   You have

```
   row = members.size();
   members.set(row, m); // tries to "overwrite" instance at index = size, 
                        // which is always greater than the last index.
```

This will always throw the IndexOutOfBoundsException because there is never an index at size since it is zero indexed.